# Set from a List of Sets

Tags: python, set

I am working in Python. I have a large list `L = [X_{1}, X_{2}, ....,X_{n}]` where each `X_{i}` is a set. It is possible that for some distinct indices `i, j` we have `X_{i} = X_{j}`.
I want to create a list (or a set) `L_{1} = [Y_{1}, Y_{2}, ... ,Y_{k}]` such that the set (in the mathematical sense) `{X_{1},..., X_{n}} = {Y_{1}, ..., Y_{k}}` and `L_{1}` is of least possible length (in other-words `L_{1}` has no repetitions).

For subsequent applications I would need to access the elements of `L_{1}`. So I cannot use the `frozenset` option.

Using `set(L)` gives an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`.

I think I can solve it using a loop construction but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem in Python.

Comment: In what way does `set(L)` not work? What does your list actually look like?

Comment: @khelwood: because sets are mutable and cannot be stored in another set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (I did know that; I just thought the poster ought to have provided a better problem description than "doesn't get the job done".)

Comment: do you mean one set of all elements or remove repeated sets? if you want one set use set.union

Comment: @khelwood: I quite agree, the question is underspecified; I can see two interpretations here at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to eliminate duplicate sets, you'll need to convert them to `frozenset()` instances:

```
unique_sets = {frozenset(s) for s in L}
```

or if you are using Python 3:

```
unique_sets = set(map(frozenset, L))
```

If you need to end up with a list of mutable sets again you can produce a list of `set()` objects again with:

```
unique_set_list = [set(s) for s in unique_sets]
```

You could combine the two into a single list comprehension with a little loss of readability:

```
seen = set()
unique_set_list = [ms for ms, ims in ((s, frozenset(s)) for s in L)
                   if not (ims in seen or seen.add(ims))]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to make it more clear. Is there any way I can use the elements of the `unique_sets` in the `frozenset()` solution?

Comment: @DBS: not quite sure what you mean? You can use the elements of `frozenset()` objects just like you can use regular sets. You just cannot add or remove elements from a`frozenset()` just like you can't alter the contents of a tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay may be I dont understand it. But suppose I take `z=frozenset([1,2,2,3])`. Then how do I access the integer element `1 in the set z`?

Comment: @DBS: same way you do that in a regular `set()`: you iterate over it. `for elem in z: # do something with elem`

Comment: @Martijn `map(set, set(map(frozenset, L)))` could replace your long list comprehension solution.

Comment: @Stefan: in Python 2 that'd create intermediary lists.

Comment: @Stefan: the list comp avoids creating sets again from the frozensets; avoiding loads of object creations and destructions if the number of sets involved is large.

Comment: Ah, yes. Yours is better that way. It's missing a `)`, btw.